# Mobile Keyboard with multiple input fields

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have multiple input fields next to each other.  From one input field to another, the keyboard disappears and reappears again to create this flicker effect. How to keep the keyboard on the screen when clicking an input field while already selecting another?

Unity version: 2022.3.9f1

Answer (score 0):

Check first if [`EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject.html) could help here:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject nextInputField;

    public void SetFocusToNextInputField()
    {
        EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(nextInputField);
    }
}
```

From the discussion "[How to change selected button in EventSystem or deselect it](https://discussions.unity.com/t/how-to-change-selected-button-in-eventsystem-or-deselect-it/128688)", when a new field is selected, invoke `EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(newInputField)` to shift focus without hiding the keyboard. But if your UI also includes buttons, set their Navigation to "None" to prevent automatic selection, which could hide the keyboard.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class InputTransitionManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] inputFields;

    public void TransitionToInputField(int index)
    {
        if (index >= 0 && index < inputFields.Length)
        {
            EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(inputFields[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

You would need to assign this script to a [manager object](https://foxxthom.medium.com/game-manager-one-manager-to-rule-them-all-1c06afa72b23) and link your input fields in the [inspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingTheInspector.html).

Comment: Thanks for reply, Tried EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject. Still having Keyboard flickering issues

Comment: @Can you check with other version of Unity, for testing? Would the [2022.3.9](https://unity.com/releases/editor/whats-new/2022.3.9#release-notes) included some kind of regression?

Comment: not solved , checked in unity version 2021.3.31f1, Keyboard flickering issue there in this unity version also

Comment: @JohnRaja Strange... maybe third-party plugins or native code solutions could help manage the keyboard visibility on mobile devices.

Comment: Hey @VonC, sorry if my English sounds a bit stiff, Spanish is my first language. Got some questions about your answer:

1. Any idea why the keyboard's still acting up even after using EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject()?
2. Think this could be a Unity version issue?
3. Got any other tricks up your sleeve for fixing this that you didn't mention?

Comment: @bypabloc_ No other tricks for now. It could be a bug within the Unity engine itself, especially since it persists across different Unity versions.